# Got a wrong location in LocationManager

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have got total wrong location in my LocationManager

```
    locationService = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Log.i(log_tag, "get best provider");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    provider = locationService.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


    clearLocationCache(provider);

    Location location = locationService.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Once I was in Moscow and got a location in my application, but when I arrived in London I have got a same location on my device. I got correct location only after restarting my android device.

Comment: You are getting last known location which means your current location is not updated in Location Tracker that's why you are getting old location. i think so...

Comment: post `onLocationChanged` code please

Comment: Please post the complete code.

Comment: Are you using `GeoLocation` in your code to determine the city or area from coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

The reason comes from this line

```
locationService.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

as it always returns the last known location

Comment: Care for explanation how to force the location to refresh?

Comment: How can I force my location to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get location either by GPS or network use these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Have you given these permissions?

Comment: I have all those permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: after **locationService.getLastKnownLocation(provider);**

use the below to get new location after certain time or distance and dont forget to remove these location updates after the job is done


**locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,duration,distanceInMeter,this);**

Comment: Requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION implies a request for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```